# How do I get buttons not to sit on top of each other in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, layout

I'm having a problem with this code.  I need to dynamically add buttons to my layout.  This code works fine, with one exception.  The second button sits on top of the first.  This must have something to do with LayoutParams, but I'm not sure what.

```
private void buttonmaker (Button button)
{
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rlayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    rlayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
    rlayout.width = 100;
    button.setId(Atom.count);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         int id = v.getId();
            atoms[id].getname();
            TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textview.setText(textview.getText()+String.valueOf(atoms[id].getname()));
        }
    });
    if (Atom.count > 1) rlayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,Atom.count-1); else rlayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    button.setLayoutParams(rlayout);

    RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayout);

    v.addView(button);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the way the code posted.

Comment: *"Sorry for the way the code posted"* there's an edit button right below the tags ;)

Comment: I think you should be using the actual Id, not `Atom.count-1`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help, but I agree it makes the code cleaner.

Comment: Do you really need to use `RelativeLayout`? You won't have this problem with a `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you set de button in the relativelayout, in this component the objects are being added one above the other, you try create linearlayout global with orientation vertical or horizontal depending on what you want and added buttons, and its all

Comment: I figured out that it was  a problem in my Atom class. The buttons don't sit on top of each other anymore.  My problem now is that clicking the last button created crashes the program.